# What HTTP Status Code would represent Authenticated but requires acceptance of terms

Tags: api, http, rest, http-status-codes

I'm designing a RESTful API and systems using the API do work on behalf of a user.

We use a standard OAuth exchange to verify that user, but upon verification we may find that the user requires to accept an updated user agreement before any other methods can be allowed.  Think of the iPhone and how they change their agreements and require users to accept.

What status code would best represent this situation?  Should they be given a 401 with additional information.  A redirect?  A custom code in the 400 range?

Obviously I don't want the API consumer to think he has a valid token, but they need to know that specific actions should be taken.

Has anyone handled something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`403 Forbidden`

With additional information about the reason of course. This will show that you have understood the request, and you can state your reasons for refusing to comply.